# SSIS Package hanging when validating Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

We are in the middle of upgrading from SQL Server 2012 to 2019.  We have an issue with any of our packages that write to Excel files.  Basically what happens is that occasionally it will hang completely and never finish.  If we don't stop the package manually it will just sit and wait indefinitely.  It is just a simple query returning < 30 rows and writing it directly to Excel.  We have tried several different things from enabling "Delayed Validation" to adding delays in the flow right before the Data Flow Task.  Some things seem to help some time but never 100% of the time.

Our SSIS server is the same SQL Server we are running queries on and is a virtual server.  The file server is also a virtual server and we access is using UNC paths.  In the old environment we had a mapped network drive but we aren't allowed to anymore. The package usually hangs after the "On information" task with pre validation for the data flow task.

At this point I am at a loss for what the issue can be and I need to figure out a solution that will keep it from stopping all packages until manual intervention.